# Linux C++: How do I display my Text application output outside of stdout?

Tags: c++, linux, bash, window

My objective is to create a game playable in the Linux terminal.  However, there is a concept that I don't know how to name, so my searches are coming up empty handed.

How do programs like `iptraf` access the output on such a low level that they can modify the background, foreground and character content of each cell as well as capturing all keyboard input instead of the shell?

I assume that somewhere, there exists a 2D array that can be modified to display custom terminal window content, but I can't name this concept so I can't search for it.  What concept am I describing?

Comment: Look up ncurses.

Comment: cool thanks. that's exactly what I needed.

Comment: Post an answer, close the question ;)

Answer (score 1):

As per the idea of [this meta-answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/106219), I'm answering this question so that i will get removed from the "unanswered" listing.

The concept you are looking for was described by @123, it's called `ncurses`.